# Need to give permissions to /tmp/cache and /tmp/templates_c but can't find them

Tags: permissions, apache2, php, chmod, vps

When I open my website it shows me this:

```
The following directories must be writable by the web server:
tmp/cache
tmp/templates_c

Please correct by executing:
chmod 777 tmp/cache
chmod 777 tmp/templates_c
or the equivilent for your platform before continuing.
```

When I run these 2 commands it tells me that these directories don't exist.

How can I solve this problem

Comment: Please do not use a CMS that insists on making its template folders writable by every single user on your server.

Answer (score 0):

The commands should be

```
sudo chmod 777 /tmp/cache
sudo chmod 777 /tmp/templates_c
```

The directories `tmp/` is actually `/tmp` and of course those files sould have been created by your application.