# Which directories should I change permission on

Tags: permissions, directory, webserver

When I open my website it shows me this

```
The following directories must be writable by the web server:
tmp/cache
tmp/templates_c
Please correct by executing:
chmod 777 tmp/cache
chmod 777 tmp/templates_c
or the equivilent for your platform before continuing.
```

Where are these two directories?

Comment: It looks like you're using CMSMS - see for example [Security impacts of chmod 777](https://forum.cmsmadesimple.org/viewtopic.php?p=55475#p55475)

Comment: You [already asked this very same question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1103442/504066) a week ago and got an answer. What was wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use find command as follow:

```
find / -name templates_c -type d 2>/dev/null
```